# Can not search my uploaded application on google play

Tags: android, publish

I have published my application yesterday on Google Play and I can see it on google.play.com when I copy the whole link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=?, but can't find it on Play Store app or in browser when only type the app name, what's the reason of the problem, can any one please tell me?

Comment: What value is assigned to `package` property of `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: the whole link is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=packagename  and i can c it on google play

Comment: but when i search it on play.google.com by just writing the app title i can not find it

Comment: Wait a while before search indexes your app.

Comment: I have published it yesterday and still i cant search it with app title ?

Comment: It can take up to three days, depending on unknown reasons :)

Comment: Hey i uploaded my application on 6th of December and i still can not search it on google play by typing Application title in search box?

Comment: @Munazza you got the solution over ur problem ?